# Mesa3d CPU or GPU?

Tags: opengl, cpu, gpu, mesa

Is it true that Mesa uses CPU to rendering? A have readed something about Mesa, but still can not understand how it really works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it true that Mesa uses CPU to rendering?

It depends on, if the GPU installed in the system is supported by Mesa/DRI and the version of the created OpenGL. If the GPU is supported, rendering will happen on the GPU. If the GPU is not supported, or lacks features required for the context version requested Mesa will fall back to a software rasterizer backend running on the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Mesa serves as the OpenGL core for the open-source DRI drivers for X.org.

DRI is an open-source framework allowing direct access to graphics hardware under the X Window System.  DRI drivers are available that take advantage of the graphics hardware chipsets.

http://www.mesa3d.org/faq.html
http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/
http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/Status